# Is there a ´right´ way to get CSFML.jl in Julia to work on MacOS?

Tags: macos, julia, sfml

I am building a game engine and would like to use `CSFML.jl` as the foundation. I have the Julia package installed on both my linux (Fedora) box and my Mac. On Linux it worked like a charm and I was able to verify the functionality with the script from the `Quick start` section on the git repo: https://github.com/JuliaMultimedia/CSFML.jl.

When I run the same code on MacOS, I get the following error:

> ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: `libcsfml_graphics` not defined

I have the latest version of CSFML (2.6.1) installed via homebrew. I have also tried the manual install suggested, where you copy the files from framework and library to /usr/local/Frameworks, but the result remained the same.

If anyone has got the `CSFML.jl` package to work on MacOS (M2 chip) and if so, can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks.